# TypeSafe Config overriding values with Environment Variables works, from System Properties does not, when

Tags: typesafe-config

I have a project that uses TypeSafe config.  It loads multiple configuration files.  One is loaded the easy way:

```
private val config = ConfigFactory.load( "test-parameters" )
```

This one seems to honor the `foo = ${?ENV_VAR}` override syntax, whether ENV_VAR is passed in via the environment, or via Java System Properties (-DXXX=).

The other config file(s) are loaded using `.parseResources()` followed by an eventual `.resolve()`.  The override syntax works fine if the variables are specified as environment variables, but nothing happens when they are system properties.  The code looks like this:

```
// we define a layered config, so that you can define values in one layer, and customize them in another
// if your environment includes sub-folders, config files are read from deepest folder first
// so that you can define values in the higher folders and override them in the more specific folder
// e.g. if the environment is "foo/bar/baz", then the order of loading config files is:
//  * application.conf
//  * conf/foo/bar/baz/config.conf
//  * conf/foo/bar/config.conf
//  * conf/foo/config.conf
//  * default.conf
def loadConfig(env: String): Config = {
  // do not allow the user to supply a relative path that tries to escape the conf directory hierarchy
  if (env != null && env.matches("(?:^|/)\\.\\./"))
    throw new Exception("Illegal Environment String")

  var c = userConfig
  if (env != null && env != "") {
    val parts = env.split("/")
    var n = parts.length
    while (n > 0) {
      c = c.withFallback(ConfigFactory.parseResources(environmentConfigFile(parts.take(n).mkString("/"))))
      n -= 1
    }
  }
  c.withFallback(defaultConfig).resolve()
}
def loadConfig: Config = loadConfig(Test.environment)
```

At first blush, it looks like a bug.  `.parseResources().resolve()` and `.load()` behave slightly differently.

Or did I just miss something?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the lack of `ConfigFactory.load()`, which automatically merges in the system properties.

By changing the initialization, as follows, it works as intended:

```
var c = ConfigFactory.load().withFallback( userConfig )
```

YAY!